# variable length matching over paths in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to allow variable length matching over multiple **paths** in Cypher?  By a path I mean something like two KNOWS traversals or three BLOCKS traversals, where KNOWS and BLOCKS are relationship types in my graph.  For example, I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
MATCH (s)-[r*]->(t) 
WHERE ALL (x in type(r) WHERE x=KNOWS/KNOWS OR x= BLOCKS/BLOCKS/BLOCKS)
RETURN s, t
```

where by "KNOWS/KNOWS" I mean something like (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)-[:KNOWS]->(c).  I want to do this without changing the data itself, by adding relationships such as KNOWS/KNOWS, but rather just as a cypher query.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this.  It's actually much easier than you think:

```
MATCH p=(s)-[r:KNOWS|BLOCKS*]->(t) 
RETURN s, t;
```

When you specify the `r`, with a colon you can indicate which types you want to traverse, and separate them by a pipe for `OR`.   The asterisk just operates the way you expect.

If you only want one type of relationship at a time you can do this:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH p1=(s1)-[r1:KNOWS*]->(t1)
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(s2)-[r2:BLOCKS*]->(t2)
RETURN p1, p2;
```

If you want exactly two knows and 3 blocks, then it's:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH p1=(s1)-[:KNOWS]->()-[:KNOWS]->(t1)
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(s2)-[:BLOCKS]->()-[:BLOCKS]->()-[:BLOCKS]->(t2)
RETURN p1, p2;
```

Comment: This solution will allow paths such as "KNOWS" and "KNOWS/BLOCKS", which aren't what I have in mind.  I have in mind that you can only traverse paths constructed from the subpaths "KNOWS/KNOWS" and "BLOCKS/BLOCKS/BLOCKS".  Am I missing something?

Comment: See edit on my answer.   I didn't catch that part in your original question.

Comment: This still allows matches such as "KNOWS" and "KNOWS/BLOCKS", unfortunately.

Comment: George - no it doesn't.   The first optional match can only match it one way, the second optional match can only match it the other way.   If you use p1 and p2 they can't mix/match KNOWS and BLOCKS.

Comment: OK, I see.  I think you still have misunderstood me.  Your solution with optional matches still permits "KNOWS", which it shouldn't, and doesn't permit matches such as "KNOWS/KNOWS/BLOCKS/BLOCKS/BLOCKS/KNOWS/KNOWS", which it should.  Please reconsider my original question.

Comment: I've updated one last time, if this isn't what you're talking about then I can't tell.

Comment: Getting closer.  Now, as stated in the title and text of my question, I'd like to do **variable length** matching over the disjunction (i.e., union) of these two paths (i.e., as a regular expression, paths described by (path1|path2)^*).

Comment: You've completely lost me.  You want 2 or 3 hops of each, but variable length?  I've already provided a query that does that (the second in my answer).  You're not refining your question at all, and based on what you keep asking for, I've already provided it twice.  This will be my last update.

Comment: `MATCH p=(s)-[r:KNOWS|BLOCKS*]->(t) 
RETURN s, t;` NOT a valid cypher statement. for 3.5.x versions