# Neo4j apply relationship multiple times in a match-query

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql, cypher

I have a two nodes in database, `arrival_airport` and `departure_airport`, And I have 1 relationship between both airports.

So, when I want select all flights between 2 destinations (BOJ->SFX) I do the following:

```
MATCH (da:Departure_Airport {airport:'BOJ'})-[f:FlightInfo]->(aa:Arrival_Airport {airport: 'SFX'})
RETURN  f, da, aa
```

The question is, how can I apply FlightInfo multiple times, in order to get also all flights with a legs? (for example: BOJ->FRA->SFX)

Maybe query should look similar to this one (with an asterix):

```
MATCH (da:Departure_Airport {airport:'BOJ'})-[f:FlightInfo]*->(aa:Arrival_Airport {airport: 'SFX'})
RETURN  f, da, aa
```

**UPDATE - Solution**

So thanks for all answers and comments. I had to create the relationships between airports properly. So my query for airport-import and automatic creations of relationships (flights) looks as follow:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///airports.csv" AS line  FIELDTERMINATOR ";"
MERGE (departure_airport: Airport {name:line[0]})
MERGE (arrival_airport: Airport {name: line[1]})
MERGE (departure_airport)-[f:Flight {departure_time:line[2], arrival_time:line[3], carrier_code:line[4], service_class:line[5], overall_conti:line[6]}]-(arrival_airport)
ON CREATE SET  departure_airport.name=line[0],arrival_airport.name=line[1], f.departure_time=line[2], f.arrival_time=line[3], f.carrier_code=line[4]
```

As result you are be able to match flights as it was answered bellow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variable length matching over paths in Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097082/variable-length-matching-over-paths-in-cypher)

Comment: @MaxKukuškin You might be interested in chapter 2 „Modeling Flights and Cities“ of the book „Neo4j Graph Data Modeling“ by Mahesh Lal. (Side note: I’m not affiliated with the author nor publisher.)

Comment: @ThirstForKnowledge , thank you for your book suggestion. It's really very useful book to my topic with a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I don't know all your requirements, but I assume a slightly adapted graph model works better for you. It could be easier, if the airport type (arrival / departure) is specified by the incoming or outgoing relationship to another airport or flight, rather than by the node respectively label itself. Therefore I'd like to suggest a change of your graph model in the following way:

```
CREATE
  (boj:Airport {name: 'BOJ'}),
  (sfx:Airport {name: 'SFX'}),
  (fra:Airport {name: 'FRA'})

CREATE
  (boj)-[:FLIGHT_INFO]->(sfx),
  (boj)-[:FLIGHT_INFO]->(fra),
  (fra)-[:FLIGHT_INFO]->(sfx);
```

Your desired query would be in this case:

```
MATCH
  flightPaths = (departure:Airport {name: 'BOJ'})-[:FLIGHT_INFO*]->(arivial:Airport {name: 'SFX'})
RETURN DISTINCT
  flightPaths;
```

Comment: That said you should probably have an upper bound that makes sense on that variable-length relationships, as you probably want to limit the number of stops between the departure and arrival.

Comment: @InverseFalcon, good point! It could be done with [:FLIGHT_INFO*0..2], where  0 is lower bound and 2 is the upper bound.  The full query : MATCH
  flightPaths = (departure:Airport {name: 'BOJ'})-[:FLIGHT_INFO*0..2]->(arivial:Airport {name: 'SFX'})
RETURN DISTINCT
  flightPaths;